# How to execute bash commands in aws lambda

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to schedule a job in AWS lambda where i get data fromm a Json API. I want to transfer JSON file to amazon S3 everytime.I have set up S3 bucket and aws lambda function with proper IAM roles. I am writing AWS lambda function in Python. Code works fine on an EC2 instance but It's not transferring file to S3 if I put it in AWS Lambda.

```
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #changing the directory to /tmp
    os.chdir("/tmp")
    print "loading function"
    #downloading file to 
    os.system("wget https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 -P /tmp")
    #using aws-cli to transfer file to amazon S3
    os.system("aws s3 sync . s3://targetbucket")
```

I am new to aws lambda. I am not getting any error but it's not giving me expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda does not have the `aws cli` by default.

You can either Create a [deployment package](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) with `awscli` in it or Use python `boto3` library.

```
import boto3

s3client = boto3.client('s3')
for filename in os.listdir('/tmp'): # assuming there will not be any sub-directories
    fpath = os.path.join('/tmp',filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fpath): 
        s3client.upload_file(fpath, 'targetbucket', filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code is working fine. It seems I am not able to download file using - os.system("wget https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 -P /tmp")

do I need to create deployment package to use bash command in os.system("bash command")?

Comment: @Navjot I have never checked whether `wget` works in lambda. You can make use of `urllib` module otherwise. `urllib.urlretrieve("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", "file.json")`

Comment: Yeah
It works with urllib. Thanks for your suggestion. I think I will have to deploy wget and awscli as part of deployment package.

Comment: @liferacer : how did you add `wget` to deployment package ?

Comment: @pankajanand18 He didn't, just used `urllib` instead